# I want to send url Request from my site to cross server. How can I do this in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to send request from my site to my server first with specific IP. and from my server again need to send request to cross server. And catch response on web page.
How do I do this in php or java script?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I send a cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript)

Comment: Achieving this has been discussed in hundreds of threads previously. Please attempt to implement your own solution. If you have already, please show your code so that we can observe what may be going wrong.

Comment: You could look up curl in php. This can both send post and all desired request methods you want

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem using curl 
for more information here is the link

http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php